# Taking a cross product of Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to take string data from one dataframe and substitute it with numerical values and create a cross product of the results like the following below.

I read the data into dataframes, example input coming below:

```py
import pandas as pd
shoppers = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['bill', 'bob', 'james', 'jill', 'henry'], 
                         'item': ['apple','apple','orange','grapes','orange']})

stores = pd.DataFrame({'apple' : [0.25, 0.20, 0.18], 
                       'orange': [0.30, 0.4, 0.35],
                       'grapes': [1.0, 0.9, 1.1], 
                       'store':  ['kroger', 'publix', 'walmart']})
```

Here's the resulting shoppers dataframe:

```
         item
name         
bill    apple
bob     apple
james  orange
jill   grapes
henry  orange
```

And here's the resulting stores dataframe:

```
         apple  orange  grapes
store                         
kroger    0.25    0.30     1.0
publix    0.20    0.40     0.9
walmart   0.18    0.35     1.1
```

And the desired result is the price each person would pay at each store. For example:

[image]

I'm really struggling to find the right way to make such a transformation in Pandas efficiently. I could easily loop over shoppers and stores and build each row in a brute-force manner, but there must be a more efficient way to do this with the pandas API. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution, not *cross*, but *dot*:

```
pd.crosstab(shoppers.index, shoppers['item']).dot(stores.T)
```

Output:

```
       kroger  publix  walmart
row_0                         
bill     0.25     0.2     0.18
bob      0.25     0.2     0.18
henry    0.30     0.4     0.35
james    0.30     0.4     0.35
jill     1.00     0.9     1.10
```